# Method cannot be declared, internal type

Tags: swift, swift3

I have a delegate here and I'm getting the following error:

> 'method cannot be declared public because its parameter uses an internal type'

Here is the code.

```
public protocol CaptureViewControllerDelegate: class {
    /**
     Called when the `controller` captures an image.
     */
    // "error is here" func captureViewController(_ controller: ViewController, didCaptureStillImage image: UIImage?)
}
```

Comment: Is `ViewController` `public`? Or did you mean to use `UIViewController` instead?

Answer (score 16):

Since your protocol is `public`, the access level of `ViewController` has to be as restrictive or less restrictive than `public`.

Since there is nothing as restrictive or less restrictive than `public` or `open` in Swift, then `ViewController`'s access level must be declared as `public` or `open`.

I would recommend taking a look at Apple's Swift Access Control documentation. In addition to the different access levels, the documentation also explains the difference between `public` and `open` (open being less restrictive than public).

[The Swift Programming Language - Access Control](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html)

Comment: Thanks for this useful answer, I had similar problem (not exactly matching with this question but your answer helped me to solve my problem, to solve this error) "method cannot be declared public because its parameter uses an internal type'

Comment: That's the answer!! Thanks so much!